# Javascript textboxes - Finding lowest input and filling

Tags: javascript, textbox

Okay, so here is what I'm trying to do. I have two textboxes and the user will enter a number in each one. Then, when they click the button, a third textbox should appear with the lowest number inside.

My textbox appears, but I can't get the lowest number to appear with it. Here is my code so far.

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <script>

         function addTextBox() {
         var element = document.createElement("input");

         element.setAttribute("type", "text");
         element.setAttribute("id", "Text3");
         document.body.appendChild(element);

         fill();
         }

         function fill() {
         value = Math.min(document.getElementById("Text1").value, document.getElementById("Text2").value);
         }

      </script>
      <form>
         <input type="text" id="Text1" value="Number 1">
         <input type="text" id="Text2" value="Number 2">
        <input type="button" onclick="addTextBox()">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't set the value of the input to value, only calculated it. So a correct addTextBox() function would be:

```
function addTextBox() {
    var element = document.createElement("input");

    element.setAttribute("type", "text");
    element.setAttribute("id", "Text3");
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.value = Math.min(document.getElementById("Text1").value, document.getElementById("Text2").value);
}
```

Make sure you type numbers into the input, otherwise you'd get `NaN`.